# How to Wrap D class for Python with pyd?

Tags: d

I I am trying to wrap a class and I am following the example from wrap.

this is the extern block I am using:

```
extern(C) void PydMain() {
    alias document = dstring[];
    def!(get_salt)();
    wrap_class!(
            HashCorpus,
            Init!(document[], string, string, string, uint),
            )();
    module_init();
}
```

this is the compilation error I am getting:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/class_wrap.d(526): Error: tuple index 0 exceeds 0
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/class_wrap.d(534): Error: template instance pyd.class_wrap.Init!(dstring[][], string, string, string, uint).Init.Inner!(HashCorpus) error instantiating
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/make_wrapper.d(127):        instantiated from here: shim!(0LU, HashCorpus)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/make_wrapper.d(137):        instantiated from here: class_decls!(0u, HashCorpus, Init!(dstring[][], string, string, string, uint))
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/class_wrap.d(1483):        instantiated from here: make_wrapper!(HashCorpus, Init!(dstring[][], string, string, string, uint))
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/class_wrap.d(1476):        instantiated from here: _wrap_class!(HashCorpus, "HashCorpus", "", "", Init!(dstring[][], string, string, string, uint))
source/corpushash/hashers.d(207):        instantiated from here: wrap_class!(HashCorpus, Init!(dstring[][], string, string, string, uint))
```

I am following this example: https://github.com/ariovistus/pyd/blob/master/examples/wrap/wraptest.d

I  am using the dmd compiler.

Comment: From skimming through the example folder it looks like you have to have `module_init();` before any `wrap_class`.

Comment: I tried both ways, before  and after and the result is the same.